# How do I insert multiple checkbox values into a database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC with C#, I want to insert multiple checkbox value into a column `ItemName` in my database table row. However, even when I selected more than one value, my database only successfully manages to add one value.

How do I insert more than one value into my database?

Here is my controller:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult AddPackage(Package pkg, IFormFile photo)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ViewData["Message"] = "Invalid Input";
            ViewData["MsgType"] = "warning";
            return View("AddPackage");
        }
        else
        {
            string picfilename = DoPhotoUpload(pkg.Photo);
            List<string> itemmm = new List<string>();
            IFormCollection form = HttpContext.Request.Form;

            string itemm = form["ItemName"].ToString();

            itemmm.Add(itemm);

            itemmm = itemm.Split(',').ToList();

            foreach (string itm in itemmm)
            {
                string sql = @"INSERT INTO Package(PackageName, PackageDesc, ItemName, Picture) VALUES('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}')";

                string insert = String.Format(sql, pkg.PackageName.EscQuote(), pkg.PackageDesc.EscQuote(), itm.EscQuote(), picfilename);

                if (DBUtl.ExecSQL(insert) == 1)
                {
                    double payment = Calcforpackage(pkg);
                    TempData["Message"] = "Heath Package Added";
                    TempData["MsgType"] = "success";
                    return RedirectToAction("AdminPackage");
                }
                else
                {
                    TempData["Message"] = "Package not found.";
                    TempData["MsgType"] = "warning";
                    return View();
                }
            }

            return RedirectToAction("AdminPackage");
        }
    }
```

Here is my view:

```
 <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="offset-3 control-label col-2"  >Select Items :</label>
    <div class="col-3">
      
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline " >
        <li>

            @foreach (TestItem row in ViewData["GetItem"] as List<TestItem>)
            {

                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="@row.ItemId" 
                       name="ItemName" value="@row.ItemName.ToString()" />
                <label class="form-check-label" for="@row.ItemId">@row.ItemName.ToString() </label><br />
            }

        </li>
    </div>
       
        <div class="col-4">
            <span asp-validation-for="ItemName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you for the help in advance!

Comment: Why not use multiple columns??

Comment: I want to add the value into the same column and same row, as each row has a unique ID. So in one row, I can add multiple values inside this specific column.

Comment: According to your codes, I found you use the `foreach (string itm in itemmm)` to insert multiple times with each ItemName's value. It will split  the "test1,test2,test3" to "test1", "test2", "test3" array and will insert each "test1", "test2", "test3" into database.

If you want to insert multiple item value into just one row with multiple values, you could only insert the "test1", "test2", "test3"  string array directly into the ItemName.